# How to use snoopy class in PHP?

Tags: php, html, snoopy

I'm beginner of php, I'm making simple program, and that use some crawling web site (not private information). The result that I expected is HTML CODE, like a

```
<html><head><title>blabla blabla</title></head>...................
```

But I checked the result, the screen shown up. not a raw code, for example,

```
include "Snoopy.class.php";
$snoopy = new Snoopy;

$snoopy->fetch("http://stackoverflow.com/");
echo $snoopy->results;
```

How to I get information to HTML Code? And Do you have another good parsing library in PHP? (like a beautifulsoup on Python, and Jsoup on Java)

** The result of above code : not a html code, but screen **

[image: not html source, but screen.]

Comment: what do you mean, "but screen"? you got a screen CAPTURE?

Comment: @MarcB Sorry to poor English. I want to get HTML Code, not a fully styled html. but the styled & converted screen show up.

Comment: then `echo htmlspecialchars($snoopy->results)`, or do `header('Content-type: text/plain')` so the browser won't render it.

Comment: that's what happens when you echo their code to a page, right? DOMdocument and simplehtmldom are 2 popular parsers

Comment: @RightClick Thanks. I understand now. I'm idiot...

Answer (score 1):

To see the source code using your browser instead of it rendering the HTML your last line should be:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($snoopy->results);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the html from the URL you can do this simple do this by **file_get_contents** function of php.

```
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
// echo $url -> wrong
echo $html;
```

Comment: Thanks. that's is the another way. I solved just now, using htmlspecialchars() function. Thanks...

Comment: @Juntae I'm glad to help you it use native function to get the html, i believe it would be more fast than external class.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple

```
     // Add snoopy class and initiate it
     require "snoopy/Snoopy.class.php";
     $snoopy = new Snoopy;         

    // THis fetches the html
    $snoopy->fetch("http://www.php.net/");
                  $text = $snoopy->results;
    // This fetches the text with html tags stripped
    $snoopy->fetchtext("http://www.php.net/");
                  $text = $snoopy->results;
    // This fetches all the links
    $snoopy->fetchlinks('http://www.php.net/');
    $linksarray = $snoopy->results;
```

Snoopy works great for me. So hope that helps